# Elegant way to get the first n elements of a SequenceType

Tags: swift

Is there an elegant way (think one-liner) to get the first n elements of a `SequenceType` in Swift?

I could of course write a for-loop that terminates after n elements but that's a little bulky.

Note also that the solution should be able to deal with infinite sequences.

Comment: Have you tried `foo[0..<n]` ? (`foo` is an instance of your `SequenceType`) I haven't actually tried it but I seem to recall the docs mentioning it.

Comment: You can't subscript `SequenceType`.

Comment: @RobNapier Ah, ok, well, so much for my suggestion. :)

Answer (score 21):

Isn't it exactly what `mySequence.prefix(numberOfElements)` does?

Comment: It does, but if the sequence contains less than `numberOfElements` you get a fatal error so it's not ideal

Comment: It doesn’t? It’s an explicit example in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3128808-prefix

Comment: You're right sorry. 
Try this in a repl: `print(["a"].prefix(upTo: 2))` and you get `Fatal error: Array index is out of range`.
However if you use `prefix(2)` then it's fine. I didn't see that in apple's docs!

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2, you can create this as an extension:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func take(n: Int) -> [Generator.Element] {
        var result: [Generator.Element] = []
        var g = self.generate()
        for _ in 1...n {
            if let next = g.next() {
                result.append(next)
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

In Swift 1, it would have to written as a function:

```
func take<Seq: SequenceType>(n: Int, xs: Seq) -> [Seq.Generator.Element] {
    var result: [Seq.Generator.Element] = []
    var g = xs.generate()
    for _ in 1...n {
        if let next = g.next() {
            result.append(next)
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Note that in either case, `SequenceType` does not specify what happens if you call `generate()` more than once. It could return the same values (as in an `Array`). It could return different values (as in an audio data stream). It could return nothing at all. So the caller of `take()` may need some special knowledge about its impact on the sequence.

Comment: I would implement this as a class extension for `SequenceType`. That will give the "one liner" usage desired.

Comment: SequenceType is a protocol. You can't apply extensions to protocols.

Comment: I did not realize that... hmmm. I suppose you could create a new protocol with protocol inheritance but that might defeat your intended use case. I guess a global utility function would be the way to go.

Comment: Protocols cannot have method implementations at all (so inheriting won't help you either). This approach is called a "free function" in Swift and is very common in stdlib because of that restriction.

Comment: Agreed. It would be tedious (to say the least) to define a new subprotocol and have to extend everything that conforms to `SequenceType`, just to add a simple function. A free (generic) function is the only practical solution in this instance.

Comment: Update: Today, Apple announced Swift 2.0 will include Protocol Extensions. Exactly what that means or how it will be used still remains to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

`SequenceType` only supports `generate()`.  Perhaps a more 'Swiftly' approach would be to define a `Generator` that given a start and end index and a 'base' generator would skip over the first elements, start returning some, and then stop after end index.  Like this:

```
struct SubscriptGenerator<Base: GeneratorType> : GeneratorType {
  var nowIndex : Int = 0
  let endIndex : Int
  let begIndex : Int
  var generator : Base

  init (generator: Base, startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int) {
    precondition(startIndex < endIndex, "oops")
    self.generator = generator
    self.endIndex  = endIndex
    self.begIndex  = startIndex
  }

  // MARK - GeneratorType

  typealias Element = Base.Element

  mutating func next() -> Element? {
    while (nowIndex < begIndex) { nowIndex++; generator.next () }
    return nowIndex++ < endIndex ? generator.next() : nil
  }
}
```

This is only an example.  One could define an `convenience init()` that takes a `SequenceType` and produces the base generator.  In action:

```
75> var gen = [10,20,30,40,50].generate()
76> var sg = SubscriptGenerator(generator: gen, startIndex: 1, endIndex:3) 
sg: SubscriptGenerator<IndexingGenerator<[Int]>> = { ... }
 77> sg.next()
$R2: Int? = 20
 78> sg.next()
$R3: Int? = 30
 79> sg.next()
$R4: Int? = nil
```

See Swift's `EnumerateGenerator` for an example.

Note: it might be the `Stride` nexus of Swift functionality does what you want already.

Comment: Minor critique: The API docs for the `next()` method state *"Requires: ...and no preceding call to `self.next()` has returned `nil`."* Your implementation might call `next()` repeatedly even if it has returned `nil` once. That happens if the given sequence has less than `endIndex` elements.

Comment: Yep, that is why I noted 'only an example'.  No real error checking; nowIndex incrementing forever on multiple calls.  Thanks.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it wouldn't work for infinite sequences (which were requested).

Comment: @RobNapier: Why do you think that? The `next()` method eventually returns  `nil`, even if the given sequence is infinite.

Comment: Because an endIndex is required. Nevermind… I forgot we were returning arrays here not another sequence.

Answer (score -1):

Why not

```
var seq = NominalSequence().generate()
var a = (0..<10).map({_ in seq.next()!})
```

?

Two lines, but funtional-ish.